# Как мне написать регулярное выражение для сайта pinterest

Tags: python

У меня есть функция, которая принимает в качестве аргумента 1 параметр - ссылку. Нужно проверить, является ли данная ссылка ссылкой сайта pinterest, т.е она корректная или нет. Я видел несколько вариаций ссылки этого сайта, например: "https://ru.pinterest.com...", "https://pinterest.com...", "https://pin.it..." и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Первая же ссылка в гугле со всеми доменами пинтереста: https://www.netify.ai/resources/applications/pinterest